# Gitlab.com (saas) CI runners public or private IP addresses (range)

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

Is there any official IP range for the Gitlab CI runners in Gitlab.com (saas)? I’d like to whitelist a CIDR in security group which is allowed to ssh to packer EC2 instance running in AWS?

Answer (score 2):

From https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/gitlab_com/#ip-range

> For outgoing connections from CI/CD runners we are not providing static IP addresses. All our runners are deployed into Google Cloud Platform (GCP) - any IP based firewall can be configured by looking up [all IP address ranges or CIDR blocks for GCP](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/faq#find_ip_range).

Answer (score 1):

This script will give you ipv4/ipv6 addresses.

```
curl https://www.gstatic.com/ipranges/cloud.json | jq  '[.prefixes[] | select(.scope == "us-east1") | if (.ipv4Prefix == null) then .ipv6Prefix else .ipv4Prefix end] | join(",")' 

# replace existing authorized networks with:
gcloud container clusters update CLUSTER_NAME --zone ZONE --project PROJECT \
     --enable-master-authorized-networks \
     --master-authorized-networks=YOUR_LIST_FROM_ABOVE_COMMAND
```

Beware, I have not been able to add ipv6 CIDR block to gke authorized networks.  When I wrote this, there was one listed ipv6 address: 2600:1900:4020::/44 .  Any runner running on ipv6 egress will fail to deploy a helm chart.

This could be solved by gitlab if they enabled cloud nat for their runners.

reference: https://forum.gitlab.com/t/cidr-for-gitlabs-ci-cd-runner/72350/3

Answer (score 0):

Based on the documentation in GitLab docs here https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/gitlab_com/#ip-range

> For outgoing connections from CI/CD runners, we are not providing static IP addresses. All GitLab.com shared runners are deployed into Google Cloud Platform (GCP) in us-east1. Any IP-based firewall can be configured by looking up [IP address ranges or CIDR blocks for GCP](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/faq#find_ip_range)

As you can see from the previous answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67551968/3156395), the document itself had changed and the runners now have been running within the IP address inside the scope of `us-east1`. So the suggestion here is also noted from the document in the [google cloud documents](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/faq#find_ip_range) is to create your own script to extract the collection of `ipv4Prefix` from scope `us-east1` within this [JSON file](https://www.gstatic.com/ipranges/cloud.json) provided by the docs.

> Important: In the past, Google Cloud instructed users to inspect the _cloud-netblocks.googleusercontent.com DNS TXT record (and the records it referenced). Please update your scripts or software libraries so that they read from the cloud.json file instead. The JSON file includes additional information, such as the region to which a regional external IP address is attached.

from the time I wrote this answer, the IP ranges in the scope of `us-east1` are

```
34.23.0.0/16
34.24.0.0/15
34.26.0.0/16
34.73.0.0/16
34.74.0.0/15
34.98.128.0/21
34.118.250.0/23
34.138.0.0/15
34.148.0.0/16
35.185.0.0/17
35.190.128.0/18
35.196.0.0/16
35.207.0.0/18
35.211.0.0/16
35.220.0.0/20
35.227.0.0/17
35.229.16.0/20
35.229.32.0/19
35.229.64.0/18
35.231.0.0/16
35.237.0.0/16
35.242.0.0/20
35.243.128.0/17
104.196.0.0/18
104.196.65.0/24
104.196.66.0/23
104.196.68.0/22
104.196.96.0/19
104.196.128.0/18
104.196.192.0/19
162.216.148.0/22
```